# (C) Allocate data into heap memory

Tags: c

I got integer data from 'atoi' function.

```
char value[20];
scanf("%s %s", temp1, value);
int integer_val = atoi(value);
```

and I tried allocating this data into heap memory, 1byte by 1byte. and prints 1byte by 1byte. (to use generic data type)

```
void *mem = malloc(300);
memset(mem, NULL, 300);
for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
    *(char *)(mem+j) = *(char *)(&integer_val + j);
    const char *buffer = mem;
    printf("%02x\n", buffer[j] & 0xff);
}
```

When scanf reads

```
abc 10
```

I predict terminal prints

```
0a
00
00
00
```

but it really prints :

```
0a
00
a0
f9
```

Why ?  What is a0 fp ...? T_T

Comment: What is `str_mem`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not just some fragments of code that don't compile.

Comment: Ah  Sorry str_mem is mem. I will edit this

Comment: Really funny, because `j = 0; j < 1` would execute only one iteration.

Comment: Maybe `int` in your environment is only 16-bit long?

Comment: `memset(mem, NULL, 300);` should be `memset(mem, 0, 300);`.

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on. It may warn at `(mem+j)` because `mem` is void, which has no size.

Comment: `*(char*)(mem+j)` should be `*((char*)mem+j)` or `((char*)mem)[j]`. Similarly, `*(char *)(&integer_val + j)` should be `*((char*)&integer_val + j)` or `((char *)&integer_val)[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

`&integer_val + j` is adding an integer to `int*`. This will advance the pointer by the size of `int` and moving that to out-of-range.

To move the pointer by only one byte, it should be `(char*)&integer_val + j`.